# libgdx drawing game background texture efficient

Tags: java, android, background, libgdx

I want to draw a background image for my game, that is `480x800`, the problem is, my fps drops with like 10 -15 fps.

What is the best way to draw a game background image?

- Splitting it would be a good ideea?
- Or on some devices i'm going to see thoose lines between them?

Comment: Show your code please. Drawing one background is no reason for a FPS drop to 10 or 15. There might be something else wrong. Maybe you are instantiating a SpriteBatch in your render method?

Comment: No, i'm not. If i put // before the batch.draw(backgroundtexture,0,0), the fps is like 59-61 on my phone, if I draw the background i have like 40-45 fps..

Comment: As I said, show the code please. Without it's just pure guessing. Maybe you are reloading the texture every time...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8SpW8N87

Comment: Are your clouds big transparent sprites that overlap each other? If so, this is probably a fill-rate issue. The wording of your question made it sound like the frame rate dropped **to** 10-15, not **by** 10-15.

Comment: The clouds are not the problem they are few and not big size, if i don't draw them and draw the background my fps still drops by 10 or 15 fps..